# How to interpolate theta and phi values from text file in Python

Tags: python, interpolation

I'm new to python so I have no idea where to begin on this and I was hoping I could get some help. I have a text file that has theta and phi values. See image below of how the text file is setup.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPRTY.png

Theta is the first column, phi is the second column, and the last two columns are the gain values. The theta and phi values both have a step size of two. I want to interpolate theta and phi so that they both have a step size of one. How can I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need help on (a) writing Python code or on (b) how to interpolate the data like yours? If (a), than this is too general question; if (b), use the interpolation formula, eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation - I can see in your case the arithmetic mean will suffice.

Comment: Looks like you are using Excel so presumably you are reading a .csv file (since you mentioned text file). Perhaps consider using the pandas library to read in your file. You could make something like this: `df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')` and it will allow you to manipulate it in a familiar, tabular form. Bit of a learning curve but well worth it.